# Backup tools detecting relocated files

Tags: backup, rsync, rsnapshot

Currently my favorite backup tool for my needs is rsnapshot. The only downside is the space wasted if files are just relocated. I have seen [a similar question](https://serverfault.com/q/171871) at severfault, but the author tried to implement his own solution.

In the past I used Legatos Networker and this problem was not an issue. However I am looking a cheaper alternative for my home files.

I am out of touch of all the backup tools available. Therefore I am not sure which opensource tools solve already the relocated files problem. Ideally it should be rsync based. I do not like Unison since it is not that great to keep different versions of my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BackupPC](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/f) users hardlink based pooling. So uses the space only once for files with the same content. It uses some hash based pooling so the file name doesn't matter only the content. So it handles well relocated files.